Latency on the thermal camera while using multi-threading for multiple cameras
I am trying to do some real-time image processing by openCV with videos from web-camera and thermal-camera. I am using multi-threadings methods: one threading for one camera. The simplified code is given below.
I have confirmed this code works fine for two web cameras (one laptop build-in cam and a Logitech web cam), it also works fine for a thermal camera standing alone (infiray xtherm 2). However, when I tried to take the combination of 1 webcam and 1 thermal camera, I got significant latency on the thermal camera frames. This latency automatically disappeared after I turned off the web-cam preview window.
import cv2
import threading

def simpleVideo(camName, camInd):
    cv2.namedWindow(camName) 
    cam= cv2.VideoCapture(camInd, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    while(True):
        ret, frame=cam.read()
        cv2.imshow(camName, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # exit on ESC
            break
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyWindow(camName)

camT = threading.Thread(target=simpleVideo, args=('cam',0,))
# thermT = threading.Thread(target=simpleVideo, args=('therm',1,))
camT.start()
# thermT.start()

I would like to have synchronised frames between webcam and thermal camera with reasonable frame rate, hence one can detect the hot spot within the viewrange in real time.
I am quite new in openCV and multi-threadings. I appreciate anyone can offer me some help (or other approches). Thanks in advance.

Yikes, trying to use a GUI from two separate threads, and including rendering (including rather unpredictable wait for user input there) in the image capture loop. The fact that you mention "This latency automatically disappeared after I turned off the web-cam preview window." should give you some hints as well.

Anyway, not sure what your definition of "synchronous" is, but from my perspective, I wouldn't expect to accomplish that without hardware triggering of both of the cameras (maybe possible with the IR camera, didn't read the docs, but certainly a no-go with a built-in webcam). And certainly not with the OpenCV's VideoCapture, which is just a convenience tool to help develop computer vision algorithms.

I would try running one thread that simply captures from one camera and does nothing else, and another thread that captures from the other camera. Then do all your GUI and waitKey() stuff in the main thread.
